# JPA NamedQuery get distinct column

Tags: jpa, distinct

I want to get an list of distinct City's from my User table. I thought the code below would work but gives an error:

```
User.java
@Entity
@Table(name="user_info")
...
@NamedQuery(name = "User.all.cities", query = "SELECT distinct u.city FROM User u"),
...
@embedded
private City city;

UserBusinessLogic.java:
...
TypedQuery<City> typedQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery("User.all.cities",User.class);
List<City> names = typedQuery.getResultList();
...
```

It gives: type mismatch can not convert List to List. I tried two get first user then on getResult a City but same error one line below.

I see some examples but not really tell how to get it with correct code just the SQL syntax.

Thanks for your help

Jess

Comment: Can you please paste the stack trace?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first thing which doesn't look good is that you ask for City objects but declare to get User's.

You have:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "User.all.cities", 
            query = "SELECT distinct u.city FROM User u"),

TypedQuery<City> typedQuery = 
                  entityManager.createNamedQuery("User.all.cities", User.class);
```

Where it should [be](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29):

```
TypedQuery<City> typedQuery = 
                  entityManager.createNamedQuery("User.all.cities", City.class);
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. I had the impression that I needed to use the class name where the query was defined but it is not the case as query names in JPA should be unique.

Comment: @jessarah - if you have a working solution, than please mark some answer as a correct one, to give others a sign that your question was answered.

Answer (score -2):

The code that works is:

```
results = getJpaTemplate().execute(new JpaCallback<List<City>>() {
  @Override
  public List<City> doInJpa(EntityManager em) throws PersistenceException {
    TypedQuery<City> query = em.createNamedQuery("User.all.cities", City.class);
    return query.getResultList() ;
   }
}) ;
```

Comment: You should upvote Piotor's post instead of giving yourself credit for his answer.